# cruise control and displaying reports

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol

I want my cruise control.net dashboard to display a list of unit tests that failed.  I added these to a build report in dashboard.config

```
 <buildReportBuildPlugin>
        <xslFileNames>
          <xslFile>xsl\header.xsl</xslFile>
          <xslFile>xsl\modifications.xsl</xslFile>
          <xslFile>xsl\MYCUSTOM.xsl</xslFile>          
          <xslFile>xsl\compile-msbuild.xsl</xslFile>          
        </xslFileNames>
      </buildReportBuildPlugin>
```

Everything was great until I decided to throw an error if the unit test failed so the programmer would get a notice via cctray.

Instead of outputting the information on the screen it just shows a build error.

How can I output the stuff i need to the dashboard and also have ccnet notify the user when the unit tests have failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the merge task into the publishers block.  publishers block is already run... if a task fails it stops running other tasks after it and that is why my merge never happened.

Comment: Spent 2 days searching for this, what now appears to be obvious solution! Thanks!